# get access of dictionary elements in to another class

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a class with two dictionaries .and i want access these dictionary in other class.these is my class.

```
{
    public class DictionaryLines
    {

        private Dictionary<string, string> line1dictionary;
        private Dictionary<string, string> line2dictionary;



        public DictionaryLines()
        {
            line1dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            line2dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();


            line1dictionary.Add("A1", "Miyapur");
            line1dictionary.Add("A2", "JNTU College");
            line1dictionary.Add("A3", "KPHB Colony");
            line1dictionary.Add("A4", "Kukatpally");
            line1dictionary.Add("A5", "Balanagar");
            line1dictionary.Add("A6", "Moosapeta");
            line1dictionary.Add("A7", "Bharath nagar");
            line1dictionary.Add("A8", "Erragadda");


            line2dictionary.Add("B1", "JBS");
            line2dictionary.Add("X3", "Parade Grounds");
            line2dictionary.Add("B3", "Secundrabad");
            line2dictionary.Add("B4", "Gandhi Hospital");
           }
}
```

how i can call this dictionary into other class..thank you

Comment: Make them public?

Answer (score 1):

Adding two public properties which return the fields would be the easiest way.

```
{
    public class DictionaryLines
    {

        private Dictionary<string, string> line1dictionary;
        private Dictionary<string, string> line2dictionary;

        public Dictionary<string, string> Line1Dictionary { get { return line1dictionary; } }

        public Dictionary<string, string> Line2Dictionary { get { return line2dictionary; } }

        public DictionaryLines()
        {
            line1dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            line2dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();


            line1dictionary.Add("A1", "Miyapur");
            line1dictionary.Add("A2", "JNTU College");
            line1dictionary.Add("A3", "KPHB Colony");
            line1dictionary.Add("A4", "Kukatpally");
            line1dictionary.Add("A5", "Balanagar");
            line1dictionary.Add("A6", "Moosapeta");
            line1dictionary.Add("A7", "Bharath nagar");
            line1dictionary.Add("A8", "Erragadda");


            line2dictionary.Add("B1", "JBS");
            line2dictionary.Add("X3", "Parade Grounds");
            line2dictionary.Add("B3", "Secundrabad");
            line2dictionary.Add("B4", "Gandhi Hospital");
           }
}
```

Comment: thank you Callum..But i need these into other class.

Comment: What are you saying? I don't understand what you mean by "into other class". Any class can now access these properties.

Comment: Is it possible to get Dictionary name using Key or Value

Comment: are you talking about custom indexers?

Answer (score 0):

```
//Change the scope private to public like
public Dictionary<string, string> line1dictionary;
public Dictionary<string, string> line2dictionary;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access private members in another class using reflection.

like this:

```
public class DictionaryLines
{

    private Dictionary<string, string> line1dictionary;
    private Dictionary<string, string> line2dictionary;



    public DictionaryLines()
    {
        line1dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        line2dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();


        line1dictionary.Add("A1", "Miyapur");
        line1dictionary.Add("A2", "JNTU College");
        line1dictionary.Add("A3", "KPHB Colony");
        line1dictionary.Add("A4", "Kukatpally");
        line1dictionary.Add("A5", "Balanagar");
        line1dictionary.Add("A6", "Moosapeta");
        line1dictionary.Add("A7", "Bharath nagar");
        line1dictionary.Add("A8", "Erragadda");


        line2dictionary.Add("B1", "JBS");
        line2dictionary.Add("X3", "Parade Grounds");
        line2dictionary.Add("B3", "Secundrabad");
        line2dictionary.Add("B4", "Gandhi Hospital");
    }
} 
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var cls = new DictionaryLines().GetType();

        var attrs = cls.GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

        foreach(var k in attrs)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("----------------------"+k.Name+"------------------------------");
            foreach (var j in (Dictionary<string, string>)k.GetValue(new DictionaryLines()))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Key = "+j.Key +" & Value = "+j.Value);
            }
        }

        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

Comment: @peeter6264 I think this can be helpful for you.